# Using Puppeteer, how can I open a page, get the data and navigate to the previous page with that data within a loop

Tags: java, node.js, puppeteer

Using Puppeteer, I would like to get all the elements on a page with a particular class name and then loop through and click each one and go back to the other page with that data from the page clicked.

I have tried this:

```
await page.goto('https://myschool.ng/classroom/christian-religious-knowledge-crk?exam_type=jamb&exam_year=2019', {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 100000})
  let  questions=  await page.$$('div.media-body') 
  let data = [] 
  await questions.forEach(async (element, i)=>{
         let question =  await  element.$eval(".question-desc.mt-0.mb-3 > p", el=>el.innerHTML)
         let options =   await element.$$eval("ul >li",el=>el.map(option=>option.innerHTML))
          await page.waitFor(2000)

          await element.$eval('a', el=>el.click())
          await page.waitForSelector("h5.text-success.mb-3")
          let correctOption = await page.$eval('h5.text-success.mb-3', el=>el.innerHTML)
          //data.push({question, options, correctOption})
          page.goBack()
          console.log({question, options, correctOption}, i)
    })
```

but I always keep getting this in my console log:

```
   question: 'The core of Saul\'s disobedience was that_____________',
  options:
   [ '\n            <strong>A.</strong>\n            He freed the Kenites\n        ',
     '\n            <strong>B.</strong>\n            He refused to carry out God\'s assignment on eliminating the Amalekites\n        ',
     '\n            <strong>C.</strong>\n            He didn\'t perform the task of smiting Amalekites to the letter\n        ',
     '\n            <strong>D.</strong>\n            He preserved the booty for himself\n        ' ],
  correctOption: 'Correct Answer: Option D' } 0
{ question:
   'God instructed Saul to utterly destroy Amalek because___________',
  options:
   [ '\n            <strong>A.</strong>\n            He abhors Idolatory and all forms of Unrighteousness\n        ',
     '\n            <strong>B.</strong>\n            Its people opposed the Israelites on the way after departing Egypt\n        ',
     '\n            <strong>C.</strong>\n            Its people encouraged Israel to disobey God\n        ',
     '\n            <strong>D.</strong>\n            Samuel had prayed for it destruction\n        ' ],
  correctOption: 'Correct Answer: Option D' } 1
{ question:
   'One of the most significant lessons from the emergence of Deborah as a leader is that_________',
  options:
   [ '\n            <strong>A.</strong>\n            She not only prophesied but also advised Israel\n        ',
     '\n            <strong>B.</strong>\n            Gender difference isn\'t a limitation to leadership\n        ',
     '\n            <strong>C.</strong>\n            Honesty and Integrity are key to leadership\n        ',
     '\n            <strong>D.</strong>\n            One needs to summon courage as a leader to solve problems\n        ' ],
  correctOption: 'Correct Answer: Option D' } 2
{ question:
   'Jeremiah prophesied God\'s punishment of the Israelites because they had_______',
  options:
   [ '\n            <strong>A.</strong>\n            Compromised his worship\n        ',
     '\n            <strong>B.</strong>\n            Committed atrocities with their neighbors\' wives\n        ',
     '\n            <strong>C.</strong>\n            Trampled on the needy\n        ',
     '\n            <strong>D.</strong>\n            No belief in his message\n        ',
     '\n            <strong>D.</strong>\n            No belief in his message\n        ' ],
  correctOption: 'Correct Answer: Option D' } 3
{ question:
   'Jesus healed the lame man who had been sick for thirty-eight years at?',
  options:
   [ '\n            <strong>A.</strong>\n            Capernaum\n        ',
     '\n            <strong>B.</strong>\n            Samaria\n        ',
     '\n            <strong>C.</strong>\n            Galilee\n        ',
     '\n            <strong>D.</strong>\n            Betsheba\n        ' ],
  correctOption: 'Correct Answer: Option D' } 4
```

I have tried everything  but the correctOption  is not the data that I web scraped and it give displaying the first option.

Comment: Hi Daniel, please be patient. You posted 7 minutes ago. We are all volunteers, it can take some time for enough people to see your question and for someone to post an answer. Also, please read this: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: I have downvoted for the deadline begging. It is not acceptable to place **volunteers** under that kind of social pressure.

Comment: replacing `forEach` with a `for loop` would be a start. `forEach` executes synchronously

Comment: it just worked thanks a lot

Comment: am sorry for my behaviour  

Answer (score 0):

The main reason was  because forEach is asynchronously and i need  the loop to run 
in a  synchronously manner  , The finally solution is

```
await page.goto('https://myschool.ng/classroom/christian-religious-knowledge-crk?exam_type=jamb&exam_year=2019', {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 100000})
  let  questions=  await page.$$('div.media-body') 
  let data = [] 
    for (let index = 0; index < questions.length; index++) {
        let question =  await questions[index].$eval(".question-desc.mt-0.mb-3 > p", el=>el.innerHTML)
        let options =   await questions[index].$$eval("ul >li",el=>el.map(option=>option.innerHTML))
        await questions[index].$eval('.btn', el=>el.click())
        await page.waitFor(2000)
        await page.waitForSelector("h5.text-success.mb-3")
         .then( async()=>{
            console.log(await  page.$eval(" .text-success.mb-3", el=>el.innerHTML))
            page.goBack()
            await page.waitFor(2000)
            questions=  await page.$$('div.media-body') 
         })
         .catch(async ()=>{
            console.log("jsjjs")
             page.goBack()
             await page.waitFor(2000)
           questions=  await page.$$('div.media-body') 
         })
    }

})
```

Comment: or use `for(let question of questions)`, which is more readable.